# Word for research method

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm doing research for my school and I have to describe the research method that I used. 
I have had a conversation with a person in the company where I did my internship.

But I can't name the research method *interviewing* because it is not an interview. It's a conversation where the company explained the subject of the internship and answered some questions I had. If I name it an *interview*, my school will request me to have more interviews, because one interview is not a reason to do something.

Does anyone have an idea how to name this kind of research?

Comment: Why do you need to name it? Are you referencing it? In that case, you can simply call it “p.c.” (personal communication). Otherwise, I’m not sure why your school would think it fine to base research on what sounds like an informal conversation with nothing further, but not on an interview?

Comment: Don't ask me, that gave me a 3.5 for my last research. but the Personal communication is a good approach, thanks. Other option still are welcome!

Comment: Is 3.5 good or bad? 3.5 out of how many? *Personal discussion*, *personal conversation*. "Personal communication" includes *written* material (e.g. e-mails, letters, etc.) sent to you personally.

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps this belongs on http://academia.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: How about "discussion" with a company representative?

Answer (score 2):

A face-to-face conversation would seem to cover it.

Answer (score 0):

I postulate that you sought particular information from the person you had a conversation with and that being said you could label your research as an **investigation**.

> Definition: a searching inquiry for ascertaining facts